# How do I dynamically import a module in App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm trying to dynamically load a class from a specific module (called 'commands') and the code runs totally cool on my local setup running from a local Django server.  This bombs out though when I deploy to Google App Engine.  I've tried adding the commands module's parent module to the **import** as well with no avail (on either setup in that case).  Here's the code:

```
mod = __import__('commands.%s' % command, globals(), locals(), [command])
return getattr(mod, command)
```

App Engine just throws an ImportError whenever it hits this.

And the clarify, it doesn't bomb out on the commands module.  If I have a command like 'commands.cat' it can't find 'cat'.

Comment: What was the ImportError? You shouldn't be including the class name in the __import__ call - just do `__import__('commands')` (or better yet, do that statically), and it's possible that App Engine's import hooks behave slightly differently in this respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting import errors when importing this way when my folder/package was named "commands".  I renamed the package to "cmds" and everything worked.  I'm guessing there was a conflict with a builtin named "commands".  Also, I don't know if it matters, but I only passed a value for the *name* parameter when calling **import**:

```
__import__('cmds.' + command_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nick Johnson from the AppEngine team wrote up a blog post on this topic that may help you:

[Webapps on App Engine, part 6: Lazy loading](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/02/Webapps-on-App-Engine-part-6-Lazy-loading)

The whole batch of them are recommended reading.

Comment: I've actually been using his blurb since a little while after posting this question, still with no luck.  Is it possible it's a caching deal on App Engine's side?

Answer (score 0):

My AppEngine framework MVCEngine dynamically imports controller classes. The actual code in-context can be browsed on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/gae-mvc-engine/source/browse/trunk/MVCEngine.py?r=159#762).

Briefly, here's how I do it:

```
controller_name = "foo"
controller_path = "app/controllers/%s_controller.py" % controller_name
controller = __import__(controller_path)
controllerClass = classForName(controller_name, namespace=controller.__dict__)
```

and the `classForName` function:

```
def classForName(name, *args, **kw):
    ns = kw.get('namespace',globals())
    return ns[name](*args)
```

I haven't read Nick's article on Lazy Loading, referenced above, but he is pretty much the authority on things AppEngine, and he has a better understanding than I do of the (all-important) performance characteristics of different approaches to coding for AppEngine. Definitely read his article.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look on [**mapreduce.util.for_name**](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/source/browse/trunk/python/src/mapreduce/util.py) which lets you to dynamically import **class/function/method**. I promise :) I will wrap that in a blogpost.